# Making a wrapper type implementation generic

Tags: rust

I have the following wrapper type (similar to `std::io::Cursor`) to allow limiting the number of bytes read:

```
use std::{cmp, io};

pub struct Limited<T> {
    inner: T,
    pos: u64,
    limit: u64,
}

impl<T> Limited<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: T, limit: u64) -> Limited<T> {
        Limited {
            inner: inner,
            pos: 0,
            limit: limit,
        }
    }

    pub fn pos(&self) -> u64 { self.pos }
    pub fn limit(&self) -> u64 { self.limit }
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T { self.inner }
    pub fn get_ref(&self) -> &T { &self.inner }
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T { &mut self.inner }
}

impl<T: io::Read> io::Read for Limited<T> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let can_read = cmp::min(buf.len() as u64, self.limit - self.pos);
        if can_read != 0 {
            match self.inner.read(&mut buf[..(can_read as usize)]) {
                Ok(read) => {
                    self.pos += read as u64;
                    Ok(read)
                },
                e @ _ => e
            }
        } else {
            Ok(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
let mut l = Limited::new(io::Cursor::new(vec![1, 2, 3]), 1);
assert_eq!(l.read(&mut [0; 10]).unwrap(), 1);
```

Next I need to have `Limited<RefMut<Read>>` (so it owns the `RefMut`). Adding `impl<'a, T: 'a + io::Read> io::Read for Limited<RefMut<'a, T>>` makes the compiler complain about conflicting implementations.

Is there a way to have a generic implementation of `Limited` that would work for `Read`, `RefMut<Read>`, <strike>`Rc<Read>`</strike>, `DerefMut<Target=Read>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a generic implementation of `Limited` that would work for `Read`, `RefMut<Read>`, `Rc<Read>`, `Deref<Target=Read>`?

Not really.

`Read` and `DerefMut` <sup>1</sup> are both traits. What should the expected behavior be if you passed in a type that implemented **both traits**? There's [a RFC for *specialization*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) that might allow this in some form or the other. As the name says, it's usually about a more specific implementation, so I don't know how two distinct traits would fit in.

`RefMut` already implements `DerefMut`, so presumably that would be covered. I don't know how `Rc` would come into play as it's only for immutable data.

**1**: I assume you mean `DerefMut` instead of `Deref` as `Read` needs a mutable receiver.

Comment: FYI, I tried to replace a few impls for `Read` in the std crate with a generic `impl<T, U: ?Sized> Read for T where T: DerefMut<U>, U: Read`, but that impl conflicted with the impl for `&[u8]`...